# Does PHP SoapClient creates XML to be sent to webservice end point, based on WSDL file, while using CURL the XML should be manually created?

Tags: php, web-services, curl, wsdl

I am new to SOAP, and I do not understand how to choose between the two. Is SoapClient can do the same (or almost the same) like CURL? If so, why should I use CURL?

I did not find proper explanation how to choose between the two approach.